# Name for series $\sum f_n x^n / (n! (n+k)!)$

Tags: co.combinatorics, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sequences-and-series, terminology, generating-functions

Let $(f_n)_{n\ge0}$ be a real sequence. Then $\sum f_n {x^n \over n!}$ is called the exponential generating function of $(f_n)$.

Let $k\ge0$ be a nonnegative integer. If we add another factorial $(n+k)!$ to the denominator and obtain
$$\sum_{n\ge0} f_n {x^n \over n!(n+k)!} , $$
is there a name for this kind of generating functions? Perhaps "Bessel generating function"?

Comment: May I ask why you are interested in giving your series a name? I would be tempted to call it the generating function of the sequence $(f_n/(n+k)!)$.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Thanks for your comment. Because it might not be "my" series. I am quite certain that examples of this series have been studied before, maybe even some general theories exist. So if I know the name then I can search for related literature.

Comment: I guess the theory of such series relies on the bivariate egf $$\sum_{n\ge0, m\ge0} f_n [m\ge n] \frac{x^n}{n!}\frac{y^m}{m!}.$$  (here $[m\ge n]$ is $1$ or $0$ according whether $m\ge n$ or not).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no name for this kind of generating function, except in the case $k=0$, when they are called “doubly exponential generating functions”. I do not know of any applications for $k>0$.

Comment: I guess the case $k>0$ arises naturally as the $k$th derivative of a doubly exponential generating function. This would seem to reduce the study of "Bessel" generating series to that of doubly exponential ones.

Comment: It's unlikely that these will have any combinatorial applications since the product of two "Bessel generating functions" with integer coefficients won't in general have integer coefficients (by which I mean the coefficients of $x^n/n!(n+k)!$).